# Transforming arrays into the correct formats

Tags: php, array

I am still attempting to learn how to best handle arrays and iterate their values transforming them into the correct formats that are needed for my database/API.

So I have this array:

```
$arr = [
    0 => [
        'field' => [
            0 => [
                '@name' => 'first_name',
                '@value' => 'Jack'
            ],
            1 => [
                '@name' => 'last_name',
                '@value' => 'Lew'
            ],
            2 => [
                '@name' => 'email',
                '@value' => 'jack@gmail.com'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => Jack
        [last_name] => Lew
        [email] => jack@gmail.com
    )
```

To get to this I have taken the same approach I usually take:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++ ) {
    foreach($arr[$i] as $k => $v) {
        print_r($k . ': \r\n');
        if( is_array($v) ) {
            foreach($v as $key => $val) {
                $new[$i][$val['@name']] = $val['@value'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I having here is, I believe there has to be a better way to achieve the same results without being three levels deep of loops, since they are slower and just harder to debug altogether.

I would appreciate any insights on how I can make this code better in both readability and performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the key `field` exists, you could use [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map) to apply a function on each row. This function could use [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) to transform a column as keys, and another as values:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'field' => [
            ['@name' => 'first_name', '@value' => 'Jack'],
            ['@name' => 'last_name', '@value' => 'Lew'],
            ['@name' => 'email', '@value' => 'jack@gmail.com']
        ]
    ],
    [
        'field' => [
            ['@name' => 'first_name', '@value' => 'John'],
            ['@name' => 'last_name', '@value' => 'Doe'],
            ['@name' => 'email', '@value' => 'John@gmail.com']
        ]
    ]
];

$data = array_map(function($item) {
    return array_column($item['field'], '@value', '@name');
}, $arr) ;

print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Jack
            [last_name] => Lew
            [email] => jack@gmail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Dow
            [email] => John@gmail.com
        )

)
```

Comment: I like that, I like that very much... You may want to swap `'@value'` and `'@name'` in the `array_column` function. Since I want the key as the identifier, and the value in the value place.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right @Samuel. I'll update the answer. Thank you!